# Google keyword planner is giving me english words from searching from root domain url "/" even if I select other language research next js multilangue

Tags: internationalization, seo, multilingual, next.js13

My problem is as mentionned in the title , when I research with using Google keyword planner from the root domain "/" even though it is multilingual website it always gives me english version even with selecting french language , I think it is not good for SEO

I'm using next js 13 app router I followed the way described on next js documentation with i18n and [slug] with using this middleware :

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

import { i18n } from './i18n-config'

import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const localeStorage = request.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE')
  if (localeStorage) {
    return localeStorage.value;
  }
  // Negotiator expects plain object so we need to transform headers
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {}
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value))

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales

  // Use negotiator and intl-localematcher to get best locale
  let languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages(
    locales
  )

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale)

  return locale
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  )
  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request)

    if (pathname === '/') {
     return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}`,
        request.url
      )
    ) 
    }
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      // new URL(
      //   `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}`,
      //   request.url
      // )
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname}`,
        request.url
      )
    )
  }
}

export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  // matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)']
}
```

and this i18n.config

```
export const i18n = {
  defaultLocale: 'fr',
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
} as const
```

export type Locale = (typeof i18n)['locales'][number]

Please is anyone having an idea how to fix this

I tried to edite the middleware but didn't figured out , I want to ask if someone else had this issue , and is there a solutions with next js app router